# PostgreSQL и примеры

Tags: sql, postgresql

В чем отличие этого примера от нижнего?

```
 CREATE TABLE pilot_hobbies
    (
     pilot_name text,
      hobbies jsonb
    );

    INSERT INTO pilot_hobbies
      VALUES ( 'Ivan',
               '{ "sports": [ "футбол", "плавание" ],
                  "home_lib": true, "trips": 3
    }'::jsonb ),
             ( 'Petr',
               '{ "sports": [ "теннис", "плавание" ],
                  "home_lib": true, "trips": 2
                }'::jsonb
    ),
    ( 'Pavel',
               '{ "sports": [ "плавание" ],
                  "home_lib": false, "trips": 4
    }'::jsonb ),
             ( 'Boris',
               '{ "sports": [ "футбол", "плавание", "теннис" ],
                  "home_lib": true, "trips": 0
                }'::jsonb
    );
```

Второй пример: 
CREATE TABLE pilot_hobbies
        (
         pilot_name text,
          hobbies jsonb
        );

```
    INSERT INTO pilot_hobbies
      VALUES ( 'Ivan',
               '{ "sports": [ "футбол", "плавание" ],
                  "home_lib": true, "trips": 3
    }'),
             ( 'Petr',
               '{ "sports": [ "теннис", "плавание" ],
                  "home_lib": true, "trips": 2
                }'
    ),
    ( 'Pavel',
               '{ "sports": [ "плавание" ],
                  "home_lib": false, "trips": 4
    }'),
             ( 'Boris',
               '{ "sports": [ "футбол", "плавание", "теннис" ],
                  "home_lib": true, "trips": 0
                }'
    );
```

Какой из этих примеров правильный и почему? Как бы вы создали этот пример?

Comment: Думаю, следует пояснить в чём их отличие. Не очень удобно вчитываться в код, чтобы искать там отличия

Comment: В данном случае оба примера правильные. В первом случае идет явное приведение к типу jsonb (expr::jsonb), во втором неявное. Первый выдаст ошибку при попытке вставить строчку в поле отличное от типа jsonb. [В документации используется явное преобразование](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-json.html), лучше конечно следовать этому стилю, если не знаете, что творите.

Comment: в документации примеры вида `select литерал`, потому нет другого выхода кроме как использовать явное приведение типов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректны оба. `SQL` (да и вообще программирование) - вещь такая, где одно и то же можно сделать множеством различных способов.

Поскольку для простого запроса `insert into` необходимые типы данных и так ясны для СУБД - в явном приведении типов необходимости нет, так же как вы не приводите литерал `'Ivan'` явным образом к типу `text`.

---

А писать `insert` всегда следует с указанием полей:

```
INSERT INTO pilot_hobbies (pilot_name, hobbies)
  VALUES ('Ivan',
           '{ "sports": [ "футбол", "плавание" ],
              "home_lib": true, "trips": 3
}'),
         ( 'Petr',
           '{ "sports": [ "теннис", "плавание" ],
              "home_lib": true, "trips": 2
            }'
),
( 'Pavel',
           '{ "sports": [ "плавание" ],
              "home_lib": false, "trips": 4
}'),
         ( 'Boris',
           '{ "sports": [ "футбол", "плавание", "теннис" ],
              "home_lib": true, "trips": 0
            }'
);
```

Тогда если вы добавите новое поле в таблицу со значением по-умолчанию - вам не придётся исправлять все `insert` запросы в приложении.